# How to compare ItemElements of a Radcombobox with an expected string?

Tags: c#, linq, radcombobox, telerik-testing-tools

I need compare if a `Radcombobox` has `ItemElements` that matches with my expected string. Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
foreach (IRadComboBoxItem item in comboBox.ItemElements)
{
    var itemExists = comboBox.ItemElements.FirstOrDefault(items => item.Text.Contains(expectedString));
    if (itemExists == null) continue;
    itemExists.Select();
    return true;
}
```

However `comboBox.Text.Contains(expectedString)` is not supported as I'm comparing `IRadComboBoxItem` with a string. Could you please suggest how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Use linq method of `Any`:

```
return comboBox.ItemElements.Any(item => item.Text.Contains(expectedString));
```

In your above code you mixed a bit the use of different linq methods

1. In the `FirstOrDefault` - it returns the first item in a collection that matches a predicate, otherwise `default(T)`.
2. Then if it is not `null` you perform an `Select` but assign it to nowhere.
3. You have this code in a `foreach` loop - but do not use the `item` nowhere. you don't need the loop because you are trying to use the linq methods (which behind the scenes use the loops themselves)

---

Following comment what you want is:

```
var wantedItem = comboBox.ItemElements.FirstOrDefault(item => item.Text.Contains(expectedString));
if(wantedItem != null)
{
    //What you want to do with item
}
```

---

Didn't work with `RadComboBox` myself but by [this site](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/aspnet-ajax/controls/combobox/radcombobox-items/working-with-items-at-server-side) maybe:

```
RadComboBoxItem item = comboBox.FindItemByText(expectedString);
```

*I assume that if it doesn't find it returns `null`*

Comment: Thanks for your response. I corrected my code. However your suggestion didn't solve my problem. I have a combobox which is databound. So Text property is not available. item.Text is always holding null though comboBox.ItemElements returns the elements. So I'm unable to compare the strings. Further I'm using Select to select  that element from combobox that matches with the expectedString